# How to add Google Maps to Android with the latest build?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

To begin with - I have read 50 different threads on how to do this but they are all either outdated or full of errors when I try to implement them. *Also - this application is not for commercial use but a practise project for myself only.*

I followed the starndard guide on: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

The main difference is that I already have an application which is working. Pretty simple - Startpage got 5 buttons which starts intents (not fragments) to get information about different aspects.

What I want to do is to add a "Find us"-button with google maps. Every time I tried a solution (Stackoverflow threads and other guides) the application crashes and I don't even get to see the error because my logcat fills up with a billion messages because the phone is connected but the application is not running anymore (because it crashed).

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.danieboy.appname" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".startPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Strategy"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_strategy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Solutions"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_solutions" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Ongoing"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ongoing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Works"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_works" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ConversionOptimization"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conversion_optimization" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**startPage.java**

```
package com.example.danieboy.applicationname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class startPage extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);
    }

    public void starButton1Clicked(View view){
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Strategy.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }

    public void starButton2Clicked(View view){
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, Solutions.class);
        startActivity(i2);
    }

    public void starButton3Clicked(View view){
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this, Ongoing.class);
        startActivity(i3);
    }

    public void starButton4Clicked(View view){
        Intent i4 = new Intent(this, Works.class);
        startActivity(i4);
    }

    public void starButton5Clicked(View view){
        Intent i5 = new Intent(this, ConversionOptimization.class);
        startActivity(i5);
    }

    public void onMapsClicked(View view){
        //Start the maps fragment code here
    //Start the maps fragment code here
    Intent i6 = new Intent(this, mapsFragment.class);
    startActivity(i6);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**fragment_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**mapsFragment.java** (standard one from creating a fragment)

```
package com.example.danieboy.applicationname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link mapsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link mapsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class mapsFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment mapsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static mapsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        mapsFragment fragment = new mapsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public mapsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

**Build Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.danieboy.applicationname"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

**Edit - Error log:**

```
06-12 18:01:34.742  24935-24935/com.example.danieboy.applicationname E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.danieboy.applicaitonname/com.example.danieboy.applicationname.mapsFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
            at com.example.danieboy.applicationname.startPage.onMapsClicked(startPage.java:46)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "I don't even get to see the error because my logcat fills up with a billion messages because the phone is connected but the application is not running anymore" -- then use the search field to search for references to your app, such as searching on `danieboy`, which is unlikely to be used anywhere else.

Comment: Added error log now @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent i6 = new Intent(this, mapsFragment.class);
startActivity(i6);
```

`mapsFragment` is a `Fragment`. It is not an `Activity`. You cannot call `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that points to a `Fragment`.

Comment: Then how do I start the fragment here?

Comment: @Danieboy: Either wrap it in an activity, or run a `FragmentTransaction` to show it, or something along those lines. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I'll have a look at it first thing in the morning, really have to run now. Thanks for the help so far! :)